# How to prepare array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$country = explode(",",$post_array['allcountry']);

    foreach ($country as $count) {                         
        $array_set = explode("=",$count);
        pr($array_set);            
    }            
    die;
```

O:P-

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 100
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 150
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => 13
        [1] => 200
    )

    But I need this array to Array
    (
        [5] => 100,[11] => 150, [13] => 200
    )`
```

How is it possible ?

Comment: Well how does you input look like in the first place (what's in `$post_array['allcountry']`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make first value of exploded array as key and second as its value.

Following is the modified code:

```
$country = explode(",",$post_array['allcountry']);
$formattedArr = array();

foreach ($country as $count) {                         
    $array_set = explode("=",$count);
    $formattedArr[$array_set[0]] = $array_set[1];
}

print_r($formattedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change your code to be:

```
$country = explode(",",$post_array['allcountry']);
$new_arr = array();
foreach ($country as $count) {                         
    $array_set = explode("=",$count);
    $new_arr[$count[0]] =   $count[1] ;         
}  
print_r($new_arr);          
die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
$input  = '5=100,11=150,13=200';
$output = parse_ini_string( str_replace( ',', "\n", $input ) );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 100
    [11] => 150
    [13] => 200
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like this:
O:P- Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 100 ) Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 150 ) Array ( [0] => 13 [1] => 200 ) ---->>$yourArray

and you need it to be like this:
But I need this array to Array ( [5] => 100,[11] => 150, [13] => 200 ) How is it possible ?

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach($yourArray as $inside){
    $finalArray[$inside[0]]= $inside[1];
}
```